# Bad Request (400) while hosting osqa to AWS EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, osqa

I host **osqa** to AWS EC2 Ubuntu. While accessing my website, encouter `Bad Request (400)`

> Bad Request (400)

I check the log info. There is nothing in `/var/log/apache2/osqa.error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/osqa.access.log` is as follows:

> 84.97.200.240 - - [07/Jun/2015:16:26:43 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 205
>   84.97.200.240 - - [07/Jun/2015:16:26:44 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 205
>   84.97.200.240 - - [07/Jun/2015:16:28:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 205
>   84.97.200.240 - - [07/Jun/2015:16:29:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 205

I don't know what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: have you tried the same in local ubuntu environment ?

Comment: not yet. my local ubuntu doesn't install mysql, apache, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you have already renamed `settings_local.py.dist` to `settings_local.py`. Then open the `settings_local.py` and add your local host names to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

EX:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('yourhostname.com','localhost','127.0.0.1',)
```

Comment: thx. Now, I can access my website but encounter `500 Server Error`. And the error log file `/var/log/apache2/osqa.error.log` is empty.

Comment: What's your installed version of markdown? There is an incompatibility issue in OSQA with the new versions of markdown. Try 2.4.1. Command "pip install "markdown==2.4.1".